# Number of solutions to a binary weight equation

Tags: code-golf, binary, counting

We define \$a(n)\$ as the 1-indexed position of \$n\$ in the sequence of positive integers with the same binary weight, i.e. the same number of 1's in their binary representation. This is [A263017](https://oeis.org/A263017).

Given a positive integer \$n\$, your task is to determine how many positive integers \$k\$ satisfy:

$$k-a(k)=n$$

For instance, \$n=6\$ can be expressed as:

- \$n=7-a(7)=7-1\$ (\$7\$ being the 1<sup>st</sup> integer with 3 bits set)
- \$n=12-a(12)=12-6\$ (\$12\$ being the 6<sup>th</sup> integer with 2 bits set)

There's no other \$k\$ such that \$k-a(k)=6\$. So the expected answer is \$2\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

#### Test cases

```
Input Output
1     1
6     2
7     0
25    4
43    0
62    1
103   5
1000  0
1012  6
2000  1
3705  7
4377  8
```

Or as lists:

```
Input : [1, 6, 7, 25, 43, 62, 103, 1000, 1012, 2000, 3705, 4377]
Output: [1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 1, 5, 0, 6, 1, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 12):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
t4*:tB!s&=Rs-=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8REy6rESbFYzTaoWNe2@P9/E2NzcwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L/ERMuqxEmxWM02qFjXtvi/S8h/Qy4zLnMuI1MuE2MuMyMuQwNjIDYwABKGRlxGIJaxuQFI1twcAA).

This makes use of the following result:

### Claim

\$a(n) \le 3n/4\$ for \$n \geq 3\$.

Here is a [graphical illustration](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%3AtB%21s%26%3DRsXG1IZG3%2a4%2FXG&inputs=50&version=22.2.1). The bound is quite loose, but it is sufficient to establish that only a *finite* number of values of \$k\$ need to be tested for a given \$n\$ (more on that in “How the code works”).

**Proof**

The sequence \$a(n)\$ ([A263017](https://oeis.org/A263017)) is the amount of numbers in the set \$\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\$ that have the same binary weight as \$n\$. The binary expansion of \$n\$ has \$b \leq \log_2 n + 1\$ digits, with a leading 1. Let \$w\$ be the binary weight of \$n\$. Clearly \$w \in \{0,\ldots,b\}\$.

The number of unique permutations of the binary expansion of \$n\$, not necessarily with a leading 1, is \${b\choose w}\$. \$a(n)\$ will be at most equal to this value. It can be less, because some of the permutations may produce a number exceeding \$n\$. Thus,

$$
a(n) \leq {b\choose w}.
$$

For \$b\$ even, the [bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)

$$
{2m \choose m} \leq \frac{4^m}{\sqrt{3m+1}} \text{ for all } m \geq 1
$$

and the fact that \${b\choose w} \leq {b\choose b/2}\$ imply that

$$
{b \choose w} \leq \frac{2^b}{\sqrt{\frac{3b+2}{2}}}.
$$

For \$b\$ not necessarily even, the bound holds with \$b\$ replaced by \$b+1\$:

$$
{b \choose w} \leq \frac{2^{b+1}}{\sqrt{\frac{3b+5}{2}}}.
$$

Since \$b \leq \log_2 n + 1\$,

$$
a(n) \leq {b\choose w} \leq \frac{2^{b+1}}{\sqrt{\frac{3b+5}{2}}} \leq \frac{4n}{\sqrt{ 3/2 \cdot \log_2 n + 4}}.
$$

This is less than \$3n/4\$ for \$n \geq 80478\$, because

$$
\sqrt{3/2 \cdot \log_2 80478 + 4}\ = 5.3333348 > 16/3.
$$

For \$n = 3, \ldots, 80477 \$, direct computation of \$a(n)\$ shows that \$a(n) \leq 3n/4\$. Therefore \$a(n) \leq 3n/4\$ for \$n \geq 3\$.

### How the code works

The above result implies that

$$
k-a(k) \geq k / 4.
$$

for all \$k \geq 3\$. Thus, given \$n\$, to compute the number of positive integers \$k\$ that satisfy

$$
k-a(k)\ = n
$$

it suffices to test the latter equality for \$k = 1, \ldots, 4n\$.

Consider input `1` as an example.

```
t4*  % Implicit input: n. Duplicate. Multiply by 4
     % STACK: 1, 4
:    % Range. Gives [1 2 ... 4*n]. This is the vector of k values
     % STACK: 1, [1 2 3 4]
tB   % Duplicate. Binary expansion. Gives a binary matrix, where each row
     % corresponds to a value of k
     % STACK: 1, [1 2 3 4], [0 0 1;
                             0 1 0;
                             0 1 1;
                             1 0 0]
!s   % Tranpose. Sum of each column. This gives the binary weights
     % STACK: 1, [1 2 3 4], [1 1 2 1]
&=   % Matrix of pair-wise equality comparisons
     % STACK: 1, [1 2 3 4], [1 1 0 1;
                             1 1 0 1;
                             0 0 1 0;
                             1 1 0 1]
R    % Upper triangular part. This sets elements below the diagonal to 0
     % STACK: 1, [1 2 3 4], [1 1 0 1;
                             0 1 0 1;
                             0 0 1 0;
                             0 0 0 1]
s    % Sum of each column. For each column k, this gives the amount of
     % number up to k with the same weight as k; that is, a(k). Note that
     % the condition "up to k" corresponds to having taken the upper
     % triangular part of the matrix
     % STACK: 1, [1 2 3 4], [1 2 1 3]
-    % Subtract, element-wise. This gives k-a(k)
     % STACK: 1, [0 0 2 1]
=    % Equality comparison, element-wise. This compares n with each
     % value k-a(k)
     % STACK: [0 0 0 1]
s    % Sum. Implicit display
     % STACK: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>98</s></sup> 96 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92237/surculose-sputum)!!!

```python
lambda n:sum(n==sum(bin(i).count('1')!=bin(k).count('1')for i in range(1,k))for k in range(5*n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBBbsMgEEX3PsU0WQDVtDLGDlUkcpGEhZPaCXKCLYwXjeWzu0AWLYvP/MefkYbhx996K9ZWndZ7/Th/12D34/SgVql4nY2lhn1e@sl6Sjhhbyqi7j9qewcGjAVX22tDOXYsse6PVe@WsdUpOpHTVMjyQhBeJReEZTHtsYn5pxloBkeOsEOQCEWFUIrgCgSeiyh5HpUHoHFbJCtknnJSanx1h9fAy6TBVqkII/WWp7lfOmP7DMIZQUFLPUtmcCZs1W5mv8DHAeZxgdkdm/AZetmwlYvdLw)

Brute force and very slow.

Comment: Could you explain why \$k\$ is bounded by \$5n\$? It's not immediately obvious to me

Comment: @mathjunkie Because it works for \$1\$ and it *seems* to drop as \$n\$ increases going down to \$3n\$ for larger numbers. More ad hoc experimentation than maths. :-(

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##TZBBbsMgEEX3PsU0WQDVtDLGDlUkcpGEhZPaCXKCLYwXjeWzu0AWLYvP/MefkYbhx996K9ZWndZ7/Th/12D34/SgVql4nY2lhn1e@sl6Sjhhbyqi7j9qewcGjAVX22tDOXYsse6PVe@WsdUpOpHTVMjyQhBeJReEZTHtsYn5pxloBkeOsEOQCEWFUIrgCgSeiyh5HpUHoHFbJCtknnJSanx1h9fAy6TBVqkII/WWp7lfOmP7DMIZQUFLPUtmcCZs1W5mv8DHAeZxgdkdm/AZetmwlYvdLw), using the fact that there must be exactly \$n\$ numbers smaller than \$k\$ that has different weight.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>106</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>100</s></sup> 96 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!
Saved <s>1</s> 5 bytes thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)!!!
Saved 4 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
b(n){n=n?1+b(n&n-1):0;}k;i;s;p;f(n){for(p=0,k=5*n;i=k--;p+=n==s)for(s=0;--i;)s+=b(i)!=b(k);s=p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/RbsIwDHznK7xKTAlNpLSllOFlfAjlAUILbbVQNX1AQv32zskmtEi5nH1nxzbyasw8n5nlT6vtPomJvluZ8J3CqcMGHfZYe7m@D6zXSnQ6X1lsdCcl9rG2WjvuNacVStkgd7E@s4a/EXYcne5xmr9PjWUcnovGjjAejqDhmQjYCCgEpLmAdUZRKiBRmQelPCaUSAPPChVMRTFh6FG9epCHDOuAFOaBbAKn3lvym9tpWIG5Vaajmqh8VGn5@DB0s@ilDnfn/qmX8rE1pNJmwPyHLYkK6fmEJEWI49avA3S8OpBas/HQHjmGZD9QumbR8gLyCwiXrrSRAG8RMAhfoWmL9gj7v9F2v0P4BtNimn8A)

Port of my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204766/9481), <s>much</s> a bit faster.

Comment: `b(n){n=n?1+b(n&n-1):0;}` would be 5 bytes shorter ... but ~10 times slower.

Comment: @Arnauld Who's watching timers anyway? Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: Why do you still leave the newline?

Comment: also `k++` can be merged into condition

Comment: @l4m2 Oops, thanks for pointing that out! :-)

Comment: Like how my C solution do

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU/RbsIwDHznK7xKTAlNpLSllOFlfAjlAUILbbVQNX1AQv32zskmtEi5nH1nxzbyasw8n5nlT6vtPomJvluZ8J3CqcMGHfZYe7m@D6zXSnQ6X1lsdCcl9rG2WjvuNacVStkgd7E@s4a/EXYcne5xmr9PjWUcnovGjjAejqDhmQjYCCgEpLmAdUZRKiBRmQelPCaUSAPPChVMRTFh6FG9epCHDOuAFOaBbAKn3lvym9tpWIG5Vaajmqh8VGn5@DB0s@ilDnfn/qmX8rE1pNJmwPyHLYkK6fmEJEWI49avA3S8OpBas/HQHjmGZD9QumbR8gLyCwiXrrSRAG8RMAhfoWmL9gj7v9F2v0P4BtNimn8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @l4m2 Ah, going backwards - nice one thanks! :-)

Comment: @ceilingcat That's the ticket - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 41 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{1⊥⍵=i-+⌿(⊢×∘.≤⍨∘⍳∘≢)∘.=⍨+⌿2∘⊥⍣¯1⊢i←⍳4×⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rwUdfSR71bbTN1tR/17Nd41LXo8PRHHTP0HnUuedS7Ash61LsZRHYu0gQJ2wIFQQqNQGIgnYsPrQcasSjzUdsEoEoToOberbX/08DcvkddzY961zzq3XJovfGjtomP@qYGBzkDyRAPz@D/aYdWKBgqmCmYKxiZKpgYK5gZKRgaGAOxgQGQMDRSMAKxjM0NQLLm5gA) (Assumes ⎕IO ← 1)

This is a direct translation of [Luis Mendo's really good answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204774/75323) so go give that one an upvote if you haven't.

**How it works** (reading the submission from right to left):

- `i←⍳4×⍵` multiply the input ⍵ by 4, create a range from 1 to 4⍵ and save it in the variable i for later;
- `2∘⊥⍣¯1` create a matrix of binary conversions (one col per number);
- `+⌿` column-wise sum;
- `∘.=⍨` matrix of pair-wise equality comparisons;
- `(⊢×∘.≤⍨∘⍳∘≢)` from which we extract the upper triangular part;
- `+⌿` column-wise sum again;
- `i-` the original range 1 ... 4⍵ minus the new vector;
- `⍵=` compared to the input number;
- `1⊥` and summed up.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 70 bytes

```javascript
n=>f=(i=g=i=>+i&&1+g(i&i-1))=>i>5*n?0:(i-(g[j=g(i)]=-~g[j])==n)+f(-~i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrLDoIwEEX3/QpWZMZapQiYmEzd8RM@kEBphmAxYFz66whyN@e@2vJTjtXAr7fyfW2nnCZPpiFgcsRkJIehlg44ZKURybBJN/4cnYAVuEtL84Q3Ut/Z35DIo2xAfRmnqvdj39ld1zt4CB0s0iL7MxbHPyMRpwsTkRzWnMXrT0dLkYrHbrCvrqws7O/XWgYSzhTg/um2BZkcCgREnH4)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 81 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n*5)].reduce(s=>s+=++i-(g[j=g(i)]=-~g[j])==n,i=0,g=i=>i&&1+g(i&i-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU7LDoIwELz3KziR1kJpkYeXxfgdiIHwaEqwEFATL/46LrCX2ZnZ2Uxffaqlns308u3YtGsHq4UsF0Lc5rn6UnuKWSHmtnnXLV0gWzhwbnyq8x40NawA/4d7wQCsZ0B6GgxkxnUVR9s1vmJsrUe7jEMrhlHTkihnG0WSHUOS7ihJGG8Ykeh88CQ87pTchBhRyk1XUqGTkHDnipxTickUcym@upAS605DhX2Dx73hDqdXcFjw1F6HXf4)

Thank Arnauld for -3 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 71 bytes

```c
i,k;f(n){int C[99]={};for(i=k=0;i++/n/5<=k;)k+=i-++C[*C+=2-ffs(i)]==n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/BboMwDL33KyykSqEJaoBSytJsBz4DOFQpWQNaOgEHJMS3MyebqkXKi@33/GKr6FOpbTOsF5rYcDF2grIqikYuq9DPgRjZSy4MpUd7zK6yF2FPpYkoLatDSWUSaT0SEzZSWrFuXzdjSQjLzvlMVQMSlpjBmUHOIMkYnFLMEgYxTx1w7jDGQuLjNOdelOer8B7tywM1KDh5xDTzwdnH6H1BvXrchgOoR6t67AnquU3quVB40@DFDs9x/Mfe6/mikMVVgbgPOyS5wOcKcSKA0s6tA3gcOyCryVR1TSh88XvAsibB/g7ROyDux9oGDJyEwcBch8QtugY@/kZ7@x3CGay7dfsB)

WTF is happening?

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 72 bytes mainly by dingledooper

```c
i,k;f(n){int C[99]={};for(i=k=0;i++<5*n;)k+=i-++C[*C+=2-ffs(i)]==n;i=k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/BboMwDL33KyykSoEEKUApZWm2A58BHKqUrAGNToEDEuLbmZNN1SLlxfZ7frFV/KnUvhs2CE3GcDXjDFVdlq1cN6Gflhg5SC4Mpdc8GkU4UGliSqs6qqhMY60nYsJWylGgUGz7182MJIT14IzmugUJa8LgzKBgkOYMThlmKYOEZw44d5hgIfVxVnAvKopNeI/u5YEaFJw8Ypr74Oxj9L6gXj1uNgL16NSAPUGzdGmzlApvFrxY@5ymf@y9WS4KWdwViPuwR5ILfK6QpAIo7d06gMexFllN5rpvQ@GL3xbLmgTHO8TvgHicmjFg4CQMLHMdErfoW/j4G@3tdwhnsB22/Qc)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 79 bytes

```c
k;f(n){int C[99]={};for(k=0;k++<5*n;)*C+=k-++C[__builtin_popcount(k)]==n;k=*C;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9ha4MwEP3eX3EIhWhSiFprXZrtgz9DpbSprpotFmuhIP52d8lGWSAvd/fevdypzadSy6JFQ4w/tWaEvMiySk6zaPqBaMmFpvSQBEb4QU6l3lCaF8fj@dF@ja053vqb6h9mJNqvpDRCyyAX8/J9ag3xYVpZx7GoQMIUMtgxSBlECYNtjFnEIOSxBc4thliIXByn3InSdBbOo355oAYFW4eYJi7YuRi996hX19MQgLrWSmOPVz7rqHxmCm/svdihv9//sZfyuVfI4tJA7Icdklzgc4AwEkBpZ9cBPJYdkG3IWHSVL1zxNmC5Id76Apt3QFzfS@MxsBIGA7MdErfoKvj4G@3tdwhrMK/m5Qc)

Port of my Javascript answer